# selecting value from distinct inner join tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT picture.id
FROM app_instagram_picture_category category
INNER JOIN app_instagram_shop_picture picture ON category.picture_id = picture.id
INNER JOIN app_instagram_shop shop ON shop.id = picture.shop_id
WHERE category.first_level_category_id =10
AND shop.isLocked =0
AND shop.expirydate IS NOT NULL 
AND shop.expirydate >  '2014-05-20'
AND shop.owner_id IS NOT NULL 
LIMIT 0, 10;
```

I wanted to get 10 unique picture.id, with each from different/distinct shops, how do I do this? Should I use GROUP BY? If yes how?

**To clarify the question, let me put it this way:**

Say I have 10 shops, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J. I wanted to get 1 picture from each of those shop, so totaling 10 picture, each picture belongs to a different shop

Comment: had you tried distinct ?

Answer (score 0):

What is the relationship between shop.id and picture.id? It looks like one shop row can link to many picture rows. If so, there is no direct way to say "For each shop, choose only one picture." Think about it logically: how is the statement supposed to decide between different pictures from the same shop? Is it arbitrary?

I have had to build a statment (for a report) where I wanted to select one row out of a one-to-many relationship, and it didn't really matter which one I picked, so I did it by selecting the `max` primary key among the available results

```
SELECT picture.id, shop.id
FROM app_instagram_shop shop
INNER JOIN (select * from app_instagram_shop_picture p where p.id = 
          (select max(p.id) from app_instagram_shop_picture subp where p.shop_id = subp.shop_id)
    ) picture ON (shop.id = picture.shop_id)
INNER JOIN app_instagram_picture_category category ON (category.picture_id = picture.id)
WHERE category.first_level_category_id =10
AND shop.isLocked =0
AND shop.expirydate IS NOT NULL 
AND shop.expirydate >  '2014-05-20'
AND shop.owner_id IS NOT NULL
```

Please correct me if I am wrong about what you are trying to do, or the relationship between your tables.

EDIT: I see more what you are trying to do. Try this:

```
SELECT picture.id, shop.id
FROM app_instagram_shop shop
INNER JOIN (
        select * from app_instagram_shop_picture p LIMIT 0,10
    ) picture ON (shop.id = picture.shop_id)
INNER JOIN app_instagram_picture_category category ON (category.picture_id = picture.id)
WHERE category.first_level_category_id =10
AND shop.isLocked =0
AND shop.expirydate IS NOT NULL 
AND shop.expirydate >  '2014-05-20'
AND shop.owner_id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: I don't think this is what I am looking for..how will this select 10 random picture from 10 different shop with a particular category?

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT 
        picture.id
    FROM 
        app_instagram_picture_category category
        INNER JOIN app_instagram_shop_picture picture ON category.picture_id = picture.id
        INNER JOIN app_instagram_shop shop ON shop.id = picture.shop_id
    WHERE 
        category.first_level_category_id =10
        AND shop.isLocked =0
        AND shop.expirydate IS NOT NULL 
        AND shop.expirydate >  '2014-05-20'
        AND shop.owner_id IS NOT NULL 
    GROUP BY 
        shop.id
```

Comment: what if in my original query I just do a group by?

Comment: why do you need group by, while you can archive the goal without it?

Comment: because the query looks much simpler than what you have

Comment: if you use group by, you cannot get 10 picture_id of each shop (your initial goal).

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the question, I wanted to get 1 picture from each shop, of 10 shops.. so 10 picture in total each from a different shop. check my update again

Comment: in that case, simply group by shop.id, and remove limit in your query, then it's done

Comment: that's what I've been saying, but why should I remove the limit?

Comment: if you have more than 10 shops, that limit will cut off the result. If you have less than 10 shops, it's redundant.